# VLookup works in cell but not in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem where moving a VLookup function from a Cell to a Macro is returning #N/A.

Right now, I have a table that is referencing a second, unformatted table to build a formatted list. The formatted list uses a series of VLOOKUP commands to  populate, but this requires manually entering a new line and the 'SubPart' name.

I'm writing a macro that will simply read the whole source table and populate thew new formatted one with a single click.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get VLOOKUP to work when it's taken from cells to a macro.

```
Sub PopulateSubs()


On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim SubAssy, SubPart As String
Dim BomCount, i As Integer
Dim BlankRow As Long
Dim Source_Table As ListObject

Set Source_Table = Worksheets("BoMs").ListObjects("Table_Query_From_Syspro")


SubAssy = InputBox("Enter the Subassembly:")

If Len(SubAssy) > 0 Then
  BomCount = Application.CountIf(Range("Table_Query_from_Syspro[ParentPart]"), SubAssy)

 For i = 1 To BomCount

    BlankRow = Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(BlankRow, 1).Select
    SubPart = SubAssy & i
    ActiveCell = i
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SubPart, Source_Table, 2, 0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SubPart, Source_Table, 3, 0)

Next i

Else

    MsgBox "You entered an invalid value"

End If


MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
MsgBox "Sub assembly Not Present in the table."
End If

End Sub
```

VLOOKUP in the manual table was correctly working, but I cannot get it to return anything but #N/A in this application.

I have looked at similar solutions on this site, and run the macro with SubPart as "SubPart" as well as ""SubPart"" but neither term seems to help.

The source table is formatted as General for all cells, I'm not sure if this causes a type mismatch with String entries.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `Source_Table` **Dim'ed** and **Set** ??

Comment: How is `Source_Table` defined? The #N/A error indicates that the value is not found in the first column of the source table. Also check that the data type of SubPart is the same as in the first column of Source_Table, i.e. text vs. number.

Comment: It seems my problem stems from not knowing that tables need to be defined in macros; I assumed that since calling them up like this in a cell formula. To clarify, Source_Table is an existing table in my workbook that I can reference with VLOOKUP if I'm working from cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine 
...Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SubPart, Application.Range("Source_Table"), 6, False)

Comment: Thank You, I thought I had tried every form of the Range() function, but I must have missed that one. It works!

Answer (score 0):

The way you call the vlookup doesn't work is because it is a member of Worksheetfunction, try;

```
Application.Worksheetfunction.VLookup
```

This applies to most excel formulas. There are some functions that are embedded in vba like min/max/now and do not specifically have to be called through the Worksheetfunction member.

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for the response. I've added the WorkSheetFunction to the expression, but now I am getting a 1004 error when running the macro. I've pasted the entire code to the OP to help identify the problem.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, but now I only see a declaration of     Source_Table     but it isn't used in your code any more?

Comment: I have now correctly updated the OP to show the Source_Table declaration. I suppose my confusion stems from the fact that the COUNTIF function can directly reference the table I'm working from, but for some reason the VLOOKUP function requires this extra workaround that I don't fully understand. The current Macro returns the Error 1004 dialog box.

Comment: That is because VLookup expects a range, and Source_Table is not a range type variable. Try;

    ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SubPart, Source_Table.range, 2, 0)